# How to write a generalized code

Tags: matlab

I write a code for linear feedback shift register.My code is in below:

```
X=5712;

D1(1)=0;
D2(1)=0;
D3(1)=0;
D4(1)=0;
D5(1)=0;
D6(1)=1;

for i=1:X-1
  D6(i+1)=D1(i);
  D5(i+1)=xor(D1(i),D6(i));
  D4(i+1)=D5(i);
  D3(i+1)=D4(i);
  D2(i+1)=D3(i);
  D1(i+1)=D2(i);
end
```

In my code i can only use  6 shift register.I know for degree,`n=2,3,4,6,7,15,22`, the polynomial is `x^n+x+1`.As the polynomial is same for those degrees so i want to write a common code for all.

Matlab experts Please need your help.

Comment: What's the point of your `e` variables? They serve no purpose in your code. You can find `E` directly from the `D`s. Secondly don['t make `D1`, `D2`,...,`DN`. Just make a 2 dimensional matrix `D`

Comment: I want to write generalized code for mention degree .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are making separate vectors for each register. Rather make a single matrix (i.e. `D` replaces all of your `D1`, `D2`, ..., `Dn`) so that you can loop:

```
X = 20;
n = 6;
D = zeros(X, n);
D(1,n) = 1;
for ii = 1:X-1
  D(ii+1, 1:n-2) = D(ii, 2:n-1);
  D(ii+1, n-1) = xor(D(ii,1), D(ii,n));
  D(ii+1, n) = D(ii, 1);
end

E = D(:, end:-1:1)
```

Comment: The inner loop can be set to `D(ii+1, 1:n-2) = D(ii, 2:n-1);` or something alike.